# Telegram bot api

Tags: telegram-bot

Как изменить название чата имея только бота телеграмм что есть в чате и имеет права на изменение названия?

Answer (score 0):

Воспользоваться вызовом: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#setchattitle передав ему:

- chat_id (или @название_беседки)
- новое название в поле title.

Comment: в добавок стал вопрос кратковременного отключения оповещения на момент изменения названия и удаление сообщения об изменении названия чата. так как менять его в планах каждую минуту.

Comment: @БорисК был вопрос, вот ответ. Остальное другим вопросом.